# How to redirect .php?user= and .php/?party= to / using .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my first question so if I did something wrong please tell me.
I am working on a website and I have pages with urls:
example.net/profile.php/?user=username
example.net/party.php/?party=partyname
And I would like them to be:
example.net/profile/username
example.net/party/partyname
I don`t have any experience in htaccess so my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



DirectoryIndex main.php index.html index.htm index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php/?user=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^party/([^/]*)$ /view.php/?party=$1 [L]
```

But it doesnt work. If there is a solition that automatically redirects that would be perfect.
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `.php` extension using the following code in your apache .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```